# How to add select default in DropdownButtonFormField with data form API?

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu

This is my code.
I declare like this :

`var selectedEquipment;`

this is my code to add default value in dropdown

```
if(!isNew) {
      setState(() {
        selectedEquipment = intervention['equipment'];
      });
    }
```

And in my DropdownButton

```
DropdownButtonFormField(
                  value: selectedEquipment,
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down_circle_outlined),
                  iconSize: 24,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Equipment',
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: cGrey, fontSize: 14),
                    floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: cPrimary, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                  ),
                  items: equipmentList.map((item){
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: item,
                      child: Text(
                        item['label'],
                        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    );
                  }).toList(), 
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedEquipment = newValue;
                      isEquipment = true;
                    });
                    // selectEquipment(newValue);
                  },
),
```

When I run, I have this error

[image]

```
Exception has occurred.
_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 1606 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1': There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: {id: 27, label: tesy}. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value)
```

Comment: Try https://gist.github.com/vabym8/d4ed0aae5e9d9db308718f6d0c3d093d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue. I added equatable and It works fine now.

```
class Equipment {
  late final int id;
  late final String label;
  
  Equipment({required this.id, required this.label});

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is Equipment && runtimeType == other.runtimeType && id == other.id && label == other.label;

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode ^ label.hashCode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### New Answer

item returns a List type and value takes string type.
Change `value: item,` into `value: item['id']`

```
DropdownMenuItem(
      value: item['id'], 
      child: Text(
        item['label'],
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      ),
    );
```

### Old Reply(Not Working):

When your app/page initialize the value of `selectedEquipment` is empty.
For this reason it is showing the `There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value`.
Try to initialize the value of `selectedEquipment` in `initState`

```
var selectedEquipment;
setEquipmentValue(bool isNew){
    if(!isNew) {
        setState(() {
            selectedEquipment = intervention['equipment'];
        });
    }
}
@override
  void initState() {
    setEquipmentValue();
    super.initState();
  }
```

or

```
var selectedEquipment;
@override
  void initState() {
    if(!isNew) {
      setState(() {
        selectedEquipment = intervention['equipment'];
      });
    }
    super.initState();
  }
```

or you can give a value to `selectedEquipment` when declaring for first time

```
var selectedEquipment = intervention['equipment'];
```

Comment: I tried but same error

Comment: are you sure your `equipmentList` has some values mean not empty.
Can you `Print( equipmentList.toString())` and post the output?

Comment: [{id: 5, label:  lounge chair}, {id: 8, label: Air / hot water heat pump}, {id: 2, label: Air conditioner}, {id: 24, label: Chalet}, {id: 12, label: Heat pump}, {id: 18, label: Smoke detector}]

Comment: item returns a List type and value takes string type.  Change `value: item`, into `value: item['id']`